# wordpress (woocommerce): How to add items to cart from an android app in woocommerce?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am making an android e-commerce app. I need to add products to cart.. i tried using the following code:

```
AddOrUpdateCartItems($woocommerce);

function AddOrUpdateCartItems($woocommerce) {

    // Get 'product_id' and 'quantity' for the current woocommerce_add_to_cart operation
  //  $post_author=5;
    $post=get_post(5);

    $prodId = 8252;//(int)$_POST["add-to-cart"];
    $prodQty = 1;//(int)$_POST["quantity"];
    $found=false;
    if(sizeof($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() >= 0)){
             foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                if($prodId==$cart_item['product_id']) {
                        $cart_item_key=$cart_item_key;
                        $stringProdQty=(string) $prodQty;
                        $woocommerce->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $stringProdQty);
                        $prodQty=0;
                        $stringProdQty='0';
                        $found=true;
                    }
                    else {
                       $found=false;
                    }
                }
                if($found==false) {
                     $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($prodId,$prodQty);

                        }
                    }
//echo  json_encode($woocommerce);

                }
```

this seems to add product to the cart successfully. BUT WHEN CALL THIS SCRIPT FROM MY ANDROID PHONE THE PRODUCT IS NOT ADDED TO THE CART.

So how do I add products to cart for a particular user without using sessions or global variables... please help me!!

Comment: without sessions? Exactly how do you plan to identify one user from another? And note that PHP global variables have **NOTHING** to do with preserving data between requests.

Comment: by their user id.. in the app users are forced to login so they all have a unique user id

Comment: will you be passing that ID around in your cart requests? if not, then how will PHP know WHICH user added something to their cart?

Comment: Yes I will be passing the user id in my cart requests.. that way php can identify the cart... but i am not able to understand how to add products to cart other than using the above code.. but it is useless as i cannot use sessions

Comment: why can't you? your android app is going to be making http requests to your php script, so just extract the session cookie from the response headers, and pass it on to the server for every other request. just because it's an android app doesn't make it magically immune to how http works. the server will have NO Idea it's not talking to a web browser. it just sees http requests come in.

Comment: I was thinking about doing the same.. but i wanted to see if there was a less painful way to go about it.. but it looks like that is the only way to go about this.. ill try it.. thank you.. i will reply here if i need more of your assistance.. thanks once again